# how to solve the error of installing packages used npm?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to install a package with npm install and I'm getting this error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /home/gustavo/.npm/_cacache/tmp/19e88f83
npm ERR! dest /home/gustavo/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/e5/13/a4830d717806cf92a8e491b9c7de599cf9ea92cad5489e874844380fbf76c42673ba3780c9bca560d7ff4b1cc0fd9cd4a0fbe5645736de8e1f853dcee91d
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/mocha: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/gustavo/.npm/_cacache/tmp/19e88f83' -> '/home/gustavo/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/e5/13/a4830d717806cf92a8e491b9c7de599cf9ea92cad5489e874844380fbf76c42673ba3780c9bca560d7ff4b1cc0fd9cd4a0fbe5645736de8e1f853dcee91d'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/gustavo/.npm/_logs/2022-06-22T19_23_54_851Z-debug.log
```

how can I solve?